# SQL - filter duplicate rows based on a value in a different column

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have an SQL table:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|     ID      |  position |  user   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|      1      |     1     |     0   |
|      2      |     2     |     0   |
|      3      |     3     |     0   |
|      4      |     4     |     0   |
|      5      |     5     |     0   |
|      6      |     6     |     0   |
|      7      |     7     |     0   |
|      8      |     7     |     1   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

I would like to filter the duplicate row based on position column and the distinct value of user column, for the first query I need to have the following result:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|     ID      |  position |  user   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|      1      |     1     |     0   |
|      2      |     2     |     0   |
|      3      |     3     |     0   |
|      4      |     4     |     0   |
|      5      |     5     |     0   |
|      6      |     6     |     0   |
|      8      |     7     |     1   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

For the second query I need the following:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|     ID      |  position |  user   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|      1      |     1     |     0   |
|      2      |     2     |     0   |
|      3      |     3     |     0   |
|      4      |     4     |     0   |
|      5      |     5     |     0   |
|      6      |     6     |     0   |
|      7      |     7     |     0   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

What queries do I need to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: what IF it took another value (2 for example)? in this case what will you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of further information, the two queries below assume that you want to resolve duplicate positions by taking either the larger (maximum) `user` value, in the first case, or the smaller (minimum) `user` value in the second case.

First query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT position, MAX(user) AS max_user
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY position
) t2
    ON t1.position = t2.position AND
       t1.user     = t2.max_user
```

Second query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT position, MIN(user) AS min_user
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY position
) t2
    ON t1.position = t2.position AND
       t1.user     = t2.min_user
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.