# How to remove duplicate records based on a value from a different column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, duplicates

I have a query from several SQL tables:

[image]

I would like to filter the duplicates from the query result where column id has several identical values. In this example we can see that there are two ids = 1 with (firstname Miriam). Here I would like to keep the record with pcs = 2, the second record of Miriam I don't want to have it in the query result. In case of filtering the key will be based on a value of the pcs column.

[image]

How can I achieve this? My query is:

```
SELECT 
`periode_class_members`.`id`, 
`classes`.`id` AS `class`, 
`periode_class_members`.`periode`, 
`user`.`firstname` AS `firstname`, 
`user`.`lastname` AS `lastname`, 
`periode_class_members`.`status`,
`periode_class_subjects`.`id` AS pcs 
FROM `periode_class_subject_members` 
LEFT JOIN `periode_class_members` 
ON periode_class_subject_members.periode_class_member = periode_class_members.id 
RIGHT JOIN `periode_class_subjects` 
ON periode_class_subject_members.periode_class_subject = periode_class_subjects.id 
JOIN `classes` 
ON periode_class_members.class = classes.id 
LEFT JOIN `user` 
ON periode_class_members.user = user.id
where `classes`.`id` = 1;
```

Comment: For other ids, what pcs would you like to keep? In order to do this, you need to specify the rule for which to keep.

Comment: is not duplicated  pcs is different

Comment: "I have a SQL table"??  Your query has 5 tables, combines with a very unwieldy combination of outer joins.

Comment: Need logic for which duplicate line to keep.  A min statement with a giant group by isn't pretty but would work.  Why keep 2 vs 6 for Miriam?

Comment: Bave: For this example I would like to keep pcs = 2. scais: the id is duplicate, not the pcs. Gordon: expression has been corrected. Twelth: The logic is done by the program, not by the db. For this example I would like to keep pcs = 2.

Comment: If the logic is done by the program and not the database, the program will have to loop through the different id values, for every id fetch all records for that id, loop through the records until it has decided which record it wants to operate on, and do its thing with that record.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can loop within the program and sort out unwanted records. But in this case I would like to do that within the database query if it is possible. Similar to this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800911/sql-filter-duplicate-rows-based-on-a-value-in-a-different-column

Comment: Can't you just use row_number()?  `ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by ID order by PCS) as rn`.  Then make your current query an inner query and filter it by rn = 1.

Comment: @Andrew - unless he is using MySQL 8.0, `ROW_NUMBER` and `OVER` are not  available.

Comment: Please could you confirm whether the following statement is true: *"For each group of two or more rows that share the same `id` value, it is guaranteed that exactly one of them will have its `pcs` value set to 2 - and only this row should be kept"*?

Comment: **"The logic is done by the program, not by the db."** So the DBMS is oblivious to the rules. How could the DBMS possibly remove an unwanted record, without knowing which is wanted and which is not? This makes no sense. It seems Binarus has given you about the only correct answer above. Think about this. What you ask for cannot be done for obvious reasons, so you may want to delete your request altogether.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: There is no reason to delete the request. Steve shows up how to understand and resolve this request!

Comment: @Perino: Steve's solution only works for the example with pcs = 2. But that's just an example, as you said yourself. And you want the query to dismiss records, but the logic is in the program, as you also mentioned. So the DBMS would have to ask the program somehow what rules to apply. Your request as stated is still unsolved.

Comment: @Perino -- Are you saying "get rid of the row with `pcs = 2`?  Is _that_ the business logic?  Should we hard-code _that_ into any solution?

Comment: Is it ok to assume that minimum value of pcs is 2? Because if that's true than the task will become way more easy. Kindly confirm this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SQL - without views**

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(<<your query>>) AS sub1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT *
  FROM
  (<<your query>>) AS sub2
  WHERE id = sub1.id
    AND pcs <> sub1.pcs
    AND pcs = 2);
```

...with `<<your query>>` inserted in both places - omitted here for brevity.

**SQL - with views**

Similar to above but the query only needs to be plugged in once:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_unfiltered_query AS
<<your query>>;

CREATE VIEW vw_filtered_query AS
SELECT *
FROM vw_unfiltered_query AS sub1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT *
  FROM vw_unfiltered_query AS sub2
  WHERE id = sub1.id
    AND pcs <> sub1.pcs
    AND pcs = 2);
```

**Demo**

The following demo shows the results before and after the filtering using both methods described above. (For the sake of simplicity it's using a simple `SELECT` statement from a pre-populated table in place of your query.)

http://rextester.com/MXZDDJ39435

**Explanation**

The `WHERE NOT EXISTS` ensures that only rows are included where there isn't another row with the same `id` but a different `pcs` value that is equal to 2.

Comment: Great solution Steve! Not very easy, but with this approach it works! The last row, pcs <> 2 I had to adopt to pcs = 2 to get the right results. Thx for providing your solution also with rextester!

Comment: Thanks Perino. That confused me slightly at first but then realised the `NOT EXISTS` needs to *remove* duplicate rows where `pcs <> 2` - so in order to do this it actually needs to find a *different* row in the set of duplicates where `pcs = 2`. Have updated the answer and added further rows to the demo to show it working for > 2 duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques. The point is to first have a filtered list of unique results, then add the columns that cause problems. (With rules of attachment).

You can download the list of people in the subquery and attach the roles later, you can download the roles in the subquery (1) or you can group the roles in the subqueries (2).

So you can:

```
SELECT 
`periode_class_members`.`id`, 
`classes`.`id` AS `class`, 
`periode_class_members`.`periode`, 
`user`.`firstname` AS `firstname`, 
`user`.`lastname` AS `lastname`, 
`periode_class_members`.`status`,
(SELECT min(`periode_class_subjects`.`id`) FROM periode_class_subjects WHERE periode_class_subject_members.periode_class_subject = periode_class_subjects.id GROUP BY `periode_class_subjects`.`id`) AS pcs 
FROM `periode_class_subject_members` 
LEFT JOIN `periode_class_members` 
ON periode_class_subject_members.periode_class_member = periode_class_members.id 
RIGHT JOIN `periode_class_subjects` 
JOIN `classes` 
ON periode_class_members.class = classes.id 
LEFT JOIN `user` 
ON periode_class_members.user = user.id
where `classes`.`id` = 1;
```

OR (very bad example, don't do that on production)

```
SELECT 
`periode_class_members`.`id`, 
`classes`.`id` AS `class`, 
`periode_class_members`.`periode`, 
`user`.`firstname` AS `firstname`, 
`user`.`lastname` AS `lastname`, 
`periode_class_members`.`status`,
min(`periode_class_subjects`.`id`) AS pcs 
FROM `periode_class_subject_members` 
LEFT JOIN `periode_class_members` 
ON periode_class_subject_members.periode_class_member = periode_class_members.id 
RIGHT JOIN `periode_class_subjects` 
ON periode_class_subject_members.periode_class_subject = periode_class_subjects.id 
JOIN `classes` 
ON periode_class_members.class = classes.id 
LEFT JOIN `user` 
ON periode_class_members.user = user.id
where `classes`.`id` = 1
group by `periode_class_members`.`id`, 
`classes`.`id` , 
`periode_class_members`.`periode`, 
`user`.`firstname`, 
`user`.`lastname` , 
`periode_class_members`.`status`;
```

I suggest to broaden the knowledge of subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  pcm.`id`,
        c.`id` AS `class`,
        pcm.`periode`,
        u.`firstname`, u.`lastname`,
        pcm.`status`,
        MIN(pcs.`id`) AS pcs
    FROM  `periode_class_subject_members` AS pcsm
    LEFT JOIN  `periode_class_members` AS pcm
          ON pcsm.periode_class_member = pcm.id
    RIGHT JOIN  `periode_class_subjects` AS pcs
           ON pcsm.periode_class_subject = pcs.id
    JOIN  `classes` AS c  ON pcm.class = c.id
    LEFT JOIN  `user` AS u  ON pcm.user AS u = u.id
    where  c.`id` = 1
    GROUP BY  pcm.`id`, c.`id`,
              pcm.`periode`,
              u.`firstname`,
              u.`lastname`, pcm.`status` ;
```

The two substantitive changes are with the `MIN` and adding the `GROUP BY`.

If `MIN` is not the right algorithm, then change to something else.

The `GROUP BY` list is the same as the rest of the columns in the `SELECT`.

I took the liberty of giving shorter aliases for each table.

Comment: The SQL MIN() statement I cannot use, because the remaining pcs.id is not always the minimum value. The pcs.id will be given over by the program function which calls the SQL query and pcs.id can always be different. In this example the pcs.id could also be the higher value. Next time Miriam Finders pcs could be 6. This depends on the underlying value which have been choosen in a program procedure before.

Comment: Please elaborate on "choosen in a program procedure before".  Without understanding _which_ `pcs.id`, we cannot finish helping you with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a fact that pcs field has 2 as minimum value then following query should get the job done.

```
select id,class,periode,firstname,lastname,status,(Select pcs from unfiltered un
    where un.id = unfiltered.id
    order by pcs limit 1) as pcs 
from 
(your query)
group by id;
```

The above query runs successfully. I hadn't added your query to make you understand the logic I've used. Please check the demo [here](http://rextester.com/TYAG6265).

Now, I'll add your query in above solution and also modify column names accordingly.

```
Select temp.id,temp.class,temp.periode,
       temp.firstname,temp.lastname,temp.status,
       (Select pcs from temp t
           where t.id = temp.id
        order by t.pcs limit 1) as pcs 
from 
   (SELECT 
`periode_class_members`.`id` AS id, 
`classes`.`id` AS `class`, 
`periode_class_members`.`periode`, 
`user`.`firstname` AS `firstname`, 
`user`.`lastname` AS `lastname`, 
`periode_class_members`.`status`,
`periode_class_subjects`.`id` AS pcs 
FROM `periode_class_subject_members` 
LEFT JOIN `periode_class_members` 
ON periode_class_subject_members.periode_class_member = periode_class_members.id 
RIGHT JOIN `periode_class_subjects` 
ON periode_class_subject_members.periode_class_subject = periode_class_subjects.id 
JOIN `classes` 
ON periode_class_members.class = classes.id 
LEFT JOIN `user` 
ON periode_class_members.user = user.id
where `classes`.`id` = 1) as temp
group by temp.id;
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Have you tried the query? Is it working as expected?